# How to publish only WARN level logs from an EC2 to AWS CloudWatch

Tags: amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I'm streaming Application logs from an EC2 instance, and I have the AWS CloudWatch agent setup and running and publishing all log events to the Log stream. Question is: How can I only publish WARN Log Level log events?

Answer (score 0):

Not possible to stream by log level from EC2 instances. However, you can simply set up a query in Logs Insights, which filters by Log Level, and then add that query to the dashboard so you view.

Example query:

```
 FIELDS @logStream, @timestamp, @message
| FILTER @message like "[ERROR]"
| sort @timestamp desc
| limit 50
```